# How can I install one Web Application in two context roots in JBoss 4?

Tags: web-applications, jboss, contextroot

My goal is to install only one WAR file but to use test or production settings (for example to point to different databases) depending on the context root.

- mydomain.com/MyWebApp will use production settings
- mydomain.com/MyWebAppTEST will use test settings

Internally the application then should check if the context name ends with TEST to control the configuration.

Is this possible with JBoss 4?

Edit: after rethinking the problem it looks like using a dedicated test / staging server installation of JBoss is much safer. 
Installing two copies of the same web application on one server would require a lot of additional logic. For example, if the web application needs to use a different database, it has to pass a test/production mode flag to the server at the start of a session. The server must not load the database data in advance but has to wait until the client tells him which database to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy two identical copies of the same WAR file, one called `MyWebApp.war`, the other called `MyWebAppTEST.war`?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that instead of building and deploying two WARs from the same code base but with different settings?